# Error Access-Control-Allow-Origin in React JS Frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, react-pdf

I am Working on a **React JS** project. I have a separate local apache pdf file server. I am accessing any pdf file from url eg : '**http://local_server_IPaddress/dirname/sample.pdf**'. I am passing this url to display pdf file in react component but I am getting below error. Please tell me how to solve this issue.

Ref- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf
**code**

```
<Document
      file="http://local_server_IPaddress/dirname/sample.pdf"
      onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        >
          <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
 </Document>
```

**Error log in browser console**

Access to fetch at '**http://local_server_IPaddress/dirname/sample.pdf**' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: does the server at `local_server_IPaddress` allow CORS?

Comment: I don't know but I am fetching any files from url in local network. I am able to display images in my react component but not pdf file. it is throwing error

Comment: if the port is different it's a cross origin request

Answer (score 5):

Simple Solution Used for Development Purposes:

You can add this URL that allows cors before the actual URL

```
file={"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + pdf}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `proxy` field into `package.json` like this:

```
"proxy": "http://local_server_IPaddress"
```

Edit the code, and remove url of server like this:

```
<Document
  file="/dirname/sample.pdf"
  onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}
    >
      <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
</Document>
```

It should works on build environment

See more: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/